# How to use Java to set cookie to be HttpOnly using Servlet 2.3

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, path, httponly

We currently have a web project that is using Servlet version 2.3 that contains a servlet that is writing a cookie that we need to set to HttpOnly.  At first I was going to upgrade to version 3.0 so I could use the setHttpOnly() function but this caused other issues with the project so we need to keep it at 2.3 for now.  I found an example that said you could do this with the setPath function like this:

.setPath(";Path=/;HttpOnly;");

This works on my local machine but when I try to add it to Tomcat running on our servers it blows up with this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid path [;Path=/;HttpOnly;] was specified for this cookie

Any ideas on how I can make this work without having to upgrade the Servlet version?